# jqGrid tableToGrid function - remove multiselect

Tags: jqgrid

I'm trying to use the tableToGrid functionality with jqGrid.
My HTML table has a column with checkboxes because of which the tabletoGrid is automatically converting to a "multiselect" grid. How can I get the resulting grid to be a regular grid with my checkbox column and not be a multiselect grid?

Answer (score 0):

tableToGrid has optional second `options` parameter (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:table_to_jqgrid#calling_convention). For example you can use `tableToGrid("#myTable",{multiselect: false});`. So you can specify any grid [option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) inclusive [colModel](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options) where you can define the column properties.